# How to load iOS7 app scene before playing the game?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, sprite-kit

So I've been writing my first iOS app, learning objective-C and sprite kit. My "scene" is getting pretty populated and whenever I run the game in the simulator, the first fourth of a second the game kinda "jitters" and is hard to control, but then from there on out runs at 60.0fps. How do I get the scene to completely load and be ready to play before it actually starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing on a simulator will never give you accurate FPS. Always test on an actual device.

Use a texture atlas for your images. You can get more information on texture atlases from the [Sprite Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html).

Below is a code samples of how to preload a texture Atlas:

```
-(void)loadMyAtlas
{
    SKTextureAtlas *myAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"TextureAtlasName"];
    [SKTextureAtlas preloadTextureAtlases:[NSArray arrayWithObject:myAtlas] withCompletionHandler:^{
        // do something here
    }];
}
```

[Texture Packer](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) is a free app, from CodeAndWeb, which allows you to easily create a texture atlas, including animations. Try it out.

CodeAndWeb also has an interesting [article](http://www.codeandweb.com/blog/2013/09/23/spritekit-animations-and-textureatlasses) on preloading practices, texture atlases and animations.

To be complete, as prototypical suggested, here are ways to preload sound as well as fonts:

Create an iVar `SKAction *someSound;` then place the following code with the loading code of your scene `someSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"soundFileName.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO];` To play the sound use `[self runAction:someSound];`

Prototypical [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380954/delay-when-calling-sklabelnode) a question on preloading fonts:

The delay is based on the loading of your font. Best to preload fonts, sounds, and any other assets you intend to use, so that you don't have a delay when it's actually used the first time.

You can preload in your setup with : `SKLabelNode *preload = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"System"];`

Comment: Should also add fonts and audio to the list of things to preload with this answer.

Comment: Xcode also provides its own atlas texture packing mechanism